# javascript open colorbox from popup window opener?

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I have a popup window that pops up and I need to have the popup window somehow open a colorbox in the popup window opener window (http://www.webreference.com/js/tutorial1/opener.html).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, I managed to figure it out. Put the colorbox function in a function and call

`<script type="text/javascript">window.opener.lcolorbox("Uploads/LD_1861.jpg");</scrip`t>